# rails migration produce Segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

i try to run migration script.
but it produces segmantation fault.

this env is ruby2.4.4,rails5.1 on amazon linux.

```
============= WARNING FROM mysql2 =============
The options :user, :pass, :hostname, :dbname, :db, and :sock are deprecated and will be 
removed at some point in the future.
Instead, please use :username, :password, :host, :port, :database, :socket, :flags for the 
options.
============= END WARNING FROM mysql2 =========
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activerecord- 
5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:17: [BUG] 
Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000b98
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-linux]
```

why does it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could resolve by upgrading ruby